# Are there any *standard* vocabularies that provide a descriptor for usernames/screennames/handles?

Tags: web-standards, json-ld, vocabulary

For example, consider a subset of the user data provided by [the Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users):

```js
{
    "id_str": "6253282",
    "screen_name": "twitterapi",
    "name": "Twitter API"
}
```

Let’s say I want to model this information with JSON-LD. I can easily adapt *most* of this data using standards like:

- JSON-LD’s built-in [`@id` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#syntax-tokens-and-keywords)
- Schema.org’s [`name` attribute](http://schema.org/name)
- RFC 7565’s [`acct` URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7565)

```js
{
    "@id": "acct:6253282@twitter.com",
    "???": "twitterapi",
    "http://schema.org/name": "Twitter API"
}
```

(The `???` is a placeholder for the descriptor I’m seeking.)

In short: are there any standard vocabularies that I could use to replace the `???` in the code snippet above?

Answer (score 1):

The vocabulary **FOAF**¹ provides the [`nick` property](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_nick):

> A short informal nickname characterising an agent (includes login identifiers, IRC and other chat nicknames).

---

¹ Note that this vocabulary is part of the [JSON-LD Context `http://www.w3.org/2013/json-ld-context/rdfa11`](http://www.w3.org/2013/json-ld-context/rdfa11):

> ```
> "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
> ```